# Grep progress bar using pv (pipe viewer)

Tags: grep, pv

I've got a huge directory on my computer and I need to search in every ruby file inside for a string.

I could have done it like this : `grep -R "string" *.rb` but it takes really long and I'd like to use pv (pipe viewer) to show a progress bar to be able to monitor `grep` progress.

But I don't really know how can I write this command because there are still some things I just can't understand about this command.

Has someone got any idea ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`pv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) operates on ***pipes*** (not commands) -- It is a volume gauge showing how much data has gone past a given point in the pipeline.
Your grep command is *not* a pipeline (`|` - the `pipe operator` is nowhere to be found) - it's just a single command doing its thing.  `pv` can't help you here, you just have to trust that `grep` is actually doing its thing on all of the input files.

You *could* cobble something together with find, pv, xargs & grep (`find . -name "*.rb" | pv | xargs grep [regex]` looks like it might be promising, but you would have to tell `pv` how big the `find` output is for it to give meaningful results.

Frankly it seems like more work than it's worth.  Just run your grep, ***wait patiently***, and deal with the output when it's done.

Comment: It's definitely *possible*, it's just convoluted and will probably take longer to put together and get working than just waiting for the grep to finish :-)

Comment: Could be a really nice snippet :p

Answer (score 5):

Two more methods:

```
for file in *.rb; do echo $file; grep "string" $file >> output.txt; done
```

Or, in a different shell while your original command is running, find the pid of the grep command and then:

```
strace -q -s 256 -e trace=open -p [pid] 2>&1 | head
```

Both of the above will show you which file the grep command is currently working on.  You can find the total number of files with:

```
ls -l *.rb | wc -l
```

Lastly, use this to figure out which number the current file is in the list:

```
ls -l *.rb | grep -n [the current filename]
```

P.S. My answers assume that all your files are in a single directory.  If they are not, you will have to use `find` instead of `ls` and `*.rb` as thinice suggested.

Comment: That's a nice alternative

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what OS you're using, but `grep -R "string" *.ext` may not be working correctly for you.

You might be better served using `find` in conjunction with `grep`:

`find . -type f -name "*.rb" -print0 |xargs --null grep "string"`

Comment: Right, the command I've given actually works on Fedora 16 but yours is clearer. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of `pv` there is an `"-d"`-Option to watch all the FDs of another process.

So in theory `pv` will not only work as a pipe but also as a progress-indicator for a whole process. (For example, try it with the PID of your Firefox)

For the Problem above a simpler idea is the following:
While the `grep` is running, use `lsof` together with `watch`.

```
$ watch -n 1 "lsof | grep -n $PWD"
```

That way you can monitor the progress of your grep.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried

```
grep -R "string" *.rb | pv
```

I don't know if it actually works to because it doesn't know how many bits of total data to search because it is recursive?

Comment: I don't think this will do what he wants -- `pv` will be operating on the output of the grep (so even if he specified the full input size `pv` only sees the output coming out the end of the pipe -- It would be *way* under-counting bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the proc-filesystem on Linux systems, i.e.

`ls -al /proc/<pid of grep>/fd`

This lists all the files that the grep-invocation has open currently and thus gives an impression of where in the search it is currently.